# grails detached criteria ambiguous column

Tags: hibernate, grails, ambiguous

We are getting an ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined error while using DetachedCriteria filtering in grails and the domain class has multiple collections of the same class.

Our domain looks something like this:

```
class Document {
    ...
    static hasMany = [primaries : Node, secondaries: Node]

    static mapping = {
        primaries joinTable: [name: 'doc_primary',
            key: 'doc_id',
            column: 'node_id']
        secondaries joinTable: [name: 'doc_secondary',
            key: 'doc_id',
            column: 'node_id']
    }
}
```

in our controller code, we set up a DetachedCriteria object and run a query when the user wants to filter by both attributes of the Document object:

```
criteria - new DetachedCriteria(Document).build {
    def primaryIds = [1,2,3]
    def secondaryIds = [4,5,6]

    primaries {
        'in'('id', primaryIds)
    }

    secondaries {
        'in'('id', secondaryIds)
    }

}

def filteredDocs = criteria.list()
```

It looks like hibernate generates the following SQL for this query and is throwing the column ambiguously defined error (see the duplicate **doc1_8_**):

```
SELECT *
  FROM (  SELECT this_.id AS id8_2_,
                  ...
                  primaries4_.doc_id AS doc1_8_,
                  secondaries6_.doc_id AS doc1_8_
                  ...
          FROM DOCUMENT this_
              INNER JOIN doc_primary primaries4_
                  ON this_.id = primaries4_.doc_id
              INNER JOIN doc_secondary secondaries6_
                  ON this_.id = secondaries6_.doc_id
```

We were thinking we need to set up an alias or something but it looks like aliases aren't supported for [DetachedCriteria](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8741) in the current version of grails.  Is there something else we are missing?

Comment: We ended up doing a second query like this to get around it: `def primaries = Document.executeQuery("from Document d INNER JOIN d.primaries dp where dp.id in (:idList)",  [idList: primaryIds])`